# Selecting each node in SelectedNodes using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: loops, xpath, iteration, html-agility-pack

I've loaded a webpage from a URL to an `HtmlDocument`

Using `var nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='myLi']");`
I can get a `Count` of 25 nodes.

However, when I iterate through the nodes using:

```
foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in nodes)
{
    SomeList.Add(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='user']").InnerText.Trim());
}
```

I get 25 of the **same** results in the list.
I'm pretty sure the `foreach`  loop should be iterating through each node individually - where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To tell HtmlAgilityPack that your XPath scope is limited to current `htmlNode` you need to add a dot/period (.) at the beginning of the XPath :

```
foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in nodes)
{
    SomeList.Add(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='user']").InnerText.Trim());
}
```

Otherwise, HAP will search the XPath within entire `HtmlDocument` and return the first matched node again and again in every iteration, that's why you got those **same** results.

Comment: You can't be serious.... 4 hours on this and THATS the answer?? And here I was willing to settle with an array in the for loop....